# MySQL query join on the same table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

users:

```
ID  |   title
0   |   Adam
1   |   Ben
2   |   Sara
3   |   Camille
```

users_meta:

```
ID  |   user_ID |   meta_key    |   meta_value
0   |       0   |   'weight'    |   '80'
1   |       0   |   'sex'       |   'male'
2   |       1   |   'weight'    |   '93'
3   |       1   |   'sex'       |   'male'
4   |       2   |   'weight'    |   '57'
5   |       2   |   'sex'       |   'female'
6   |       3   |   'weight'    |   '71'
7   |       4   |   'sex'       |   'female'
```

Now I want to get all users that are male and weight more than 90, my query:

```
SELECT u.* FROM users AS u
RIGHT JOIN users_meta AS weight on(u.ID=weight.user_ID)
RIGHT JOIN users_meta AS sex on(u.ID=sex.user_ID)
WHERE
    weight.meta_key='weight' AND
    weight.meta_key>90 AND
    sex.meta_key='sex' AND
    sex.meta_value ='male'
```

Above query works fine for me, but I'm curious if there's a better way of doing this. If you have numerous meta data for each user then you end up with several joins on the same table to check different value.

Comment: Why aren't there simply columns for weight and sex in the users table? What do you gain by a key/value table here? In my opinion this just makes things more complicated than need be and gives room for typos and errors. But well, you can store extraterrestrial users where you'd be more interested in them being mammals or not or whether they have green skin. So well, one day your table design *may* prove superior ;-) So much for "but I'm curious if there's a better way of doing this" :-)

Comment: Table structure comes from WordPress postmeta table, currently I don't have an option to have new column for each meta key.

Comment: Okay. WordPress needs generic tables of course. When your queries get too slow or too complicated, you can always create shadow tables such as `xusers (id, name, weight, sex)` and fill them via triggers. But I'd think twice whether this is really necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily aggregate the `users_meta` table per `user_id` and only keep those user IDs that meet your criteria by applying an appropriate `HAVING` clause. Then select users for this set of desired user IDs.

```
select * 
from users
where user_id in
(
  select user_id
  from users_meta
  where meta_key in ('weight', 'sex') -- not necessary, but probably faster
  group by user_id
  having sum(meta_key = 'weight' and meta_value > 90) > 0
     and sum(meta_key = 'sex' and meta_value = 'male') > 0
);
```

Comment: Your query doesn't require additional JOIN per meta key, I tested it and I receive proper results. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can do with single `join`, e.g.:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id, u.title
FROM users u JOIN users_meta m ON u.id = m.user_id
WHERE (u.meta_key = 'weight' AND u.meta_value > 90)
OR (u.meta_key = 'sex' AND u.meta_value > 'male');
```

**Update**

If you want to get all the males with weight more than 90 then you can do with two `join` queries, e.g.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT id, title FROM user WHERE id in (SELECT user_ID FROM user_meta WHERE meta_key = 'weight' AND meta_value > 90)
) a JOIN (
  SELECT id, title FROM user WHERE id in (SELECT user_ID FROM user_meta WHERE meta_key = 'sex' AND meta_value > 'male')
) b ON a.id = b.id;
```

Comment: Won't that return all users who are either male either weight more than 90? The question wanted a AND condition, not a OR. Am I missing something?

Comment: @GuillaumeF. OP has confirmed this to be the case, thanks.

Comment: I am with Guillaume here. This doesn't match the requirement. I guess the OP was a bit too quick to accept this answer :-)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner added another query

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I will check it again today and update the accepted answer.

Comment: I did some additional testing and in fact the first query doesn't return proper values, the second one requires two JOIN's. @ThorstenKettner version works without them.